# Golang's Int flag and time.After

Tags: go, time, flags

I'm getting an `invalid operation: *timeout * time.Second (mismatched types int and time.Duration)` error when trying to run something similar to this

```
timeout := flag.Int("timeout", 30, "The time limit for answering questions.")
flag.Parse()
timeoutCh := time.After(*timeout * time.Second)
```

Just to be sure, I checked the type of `*timeout` using `reflect.TypeOf()` and it is in fact an `int`. But if I do `timeoutCh := time.After(30 * time.Second)` or use any other `int` value the code works.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
timeoutCh := time.After(time.Duration(*timeout) * time.Second)
```

You have to convert `*timeout` which is type `int` to type [`time.Duration`](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Duration). The reason why `time.After(30 * time.Second)` works is that `30` is untyped and is converted to the type of `time.Second` which is [`time.Duration`](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Duration). See https://golang.org/ref/spec#Operators. Similarly this code works

```
x := uint(42)
if x == 42 {
    println("works!")
}
```

but this code won't compile

```
x := uint(42)
y := 42 // defaults to type int
if x == y {
    println("this won't complile!")
}
```

Comment: "Except for shift operations, if one operand is an untyped constant and the other operand is not, the constant is converted to the type of the other operand." I didn't know that! Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You cannot multiply two different types, so you will need to convert the integer to a time.Duration type. You can do that by simply casting it like this:

```
time.Duration(*timeout)
```

A "unit" of time is technically a nanosecond and time.Second is one seconds worth of nanoseconds. The math works out though so you can simply say something like this for 3 seconds:

```
time.Duration(3) * time.Second
```